# How do I use the Organizational Browser in My Site

Tags: my-site, organization-browser

I want to have an overview of all users within my organization, including pictures. Pictures and business information is available on the my sites, however an overview is not possible. Probably because there is no organizational sturcture implemented in our Active Directory. How can I get an overview of all users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will either have to implement it in AD, or you can set the manager property for each user profile in SP.

Comment: Okay. How do I set the manager property. I have been searching for it but wasn't able to find it.

Comment: Go to your user profile service application.  Then click on manage user profiles.  Find a profile, and then click the dropdown and edit profile.  Find the manager field, and choose someone in people picker control.  If you have a lot of users (more than say 10 or 20), I would code this in c# or powershell.